# The Ordinal 9641 could not be located in Dll

Tags: visual-studio-2008, mfc

I have started MFC application and tried to run in the Debug mode and end up in message
 "The Ordinal 9641 could not be located in Dll".

I haven't added any code to it.I am using VS 2008 SP1

Please help me getting rid of this error.

Comment: Ordinal 9641 is CMFCBaseTabCtrl::GetVisibleTabsNum().  Some kind of DLL Hell problem, very hard to guess how you got into this pickle given that mfc90.dll is stored in the side-by-side cache.  Use SysInternals' ProcMon to find out what DLL is getting loaded.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks for quick response....How you figured out that Ordinal 9641 is CMFCBaseTabCtrl::GetVisibleTabsNum()

Comment: @HansPassant Yesterday I installed vs 2008 feature pack that might be the cause...not sure

Comment: That's already included in VS2008 SP1.  So yes, good odds that you screwed things up.

Comment: @HansPassant I run the app in debug mode and found following dll getting loaded mfc90ud.dll, msvcr90d.dll,comctl32.dll,msvcp90d.dll from c:\Windows\WinSxS folder....

Comment: It is working fine if I choose "Use MFC in a Static Library"

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. It would run in my system bot not in some other engineer's system. The change I did was "configuration properties->General->Use MFC in static library" and Runtime Library  to /MT or /MTd (C/C++ -> Code generation -> Runtime Library -> Multi Threaded Debug). It worked because it just by-passed the original dlls. It increases the exe size by a lot bt won't mind if it is run in a PC or server may be.